# Actualizar un item (datos) de un JCombobox desde varios JTextField

Tags: java

Tengo 3 JTextFields que almacenan datos de persona, cuando le doy a un botón "guardar" se vuelcan en un JComboBox. Cuando quiero editar los datos de la persona utilizo con un chechbox que hace el evento de regresar/volcar nuevamente esos datos en los JTextFields para ser editado/modificado. Hasta allí sin problema.

La cuestión es que, con un nuevo botón "modificar" quiero que si hago algún cambio de esos datos me vuelva a actualizar el JComboBox.

Tengo lo siguiente, pero no doy con ello.

```
Object evento = ae.getSource();

if(objeto == boton_modificar){

  combo.setSelectedItem(jtf_nombre.getText()+ jtf_edad.getText()+ jtf_movil.getText());

}
```

He intentado con esto también:

```
Object evento = ae.getSource();

if(objeto == boton_modificar){

  combo.setSelectedItem(jtf_nombre.getText().toString()+ jtf_edad.getText().toString+ jtf_movil.getText().toString); 

}
```

No se que estoy haciendo mal, gracias por los consejos. 
Editado desde aquí:

Con la ayuda de @SuperG280 he hecho lo siguiente, pero no logro actualizar el item.

```
if (objeto == boton_modificar) {

// obtengo la posicion del item y se lo paso a una variable 
int posi = combo.getSelectedIndex();
// elimino ese item desde su posicion 
combo.removeItem(posi);
//para ver en consola                       
System.out.println("la posicion es: " +posi);                  

// utilizo el insertItemAt para pasar al index(posi) el nuevo valor
combo.insertItemAt(jtf_nombre + "" + jtf_edad + "" + jtf_movil, posi);

}
```

Comment: Si pretendes cambiar el contenido del item de la combo box con `setSelectedItem`, ya te digo que no se puede. `setSelectedItem` busca el objeto que le pasas como parámetro en la combo box y lo selecciona. Pero no le cambia su valor. Es más, si le pasas los nuevos valores modificados, dado que no hay ningún item en la combo con ese valor, no hará nada. Tendrías que obtener la posición del item, eliminarlo y crear uno nuevo en esa misma posición.

Comment: Hola @SuperG280, he hecho lo que me has recomendado (editado el post para que se vea), sin embargo no consigo actualizar el item. Buscando he dado con el método insertItemAt, pero no consigo que lo actualice. No se si el es método adecuado o que. Saludos.